# How to sort dataframe with values

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

I want to sort my dataframe in decending order with "Total Confirmed cases"

My Code

```
high_cases_sorted_df = df.sort_values(by='Total Confirmed cases',ascending=False)
print(high_cases_sorted_df)
```

Output

```
                          state       Total Confirmed cases
19                  Maharashtra                  8590
14                    Jharkhand                    82
24                   Puducherry                     8
9                           Goa                     7
32                  West Bengal                   697
13            Jammu and Kashmir                   546
15                    Karnataka                   512
30                  Uttarakhand                    51
16                       Kerala                   481
6                    Chandigarh                    40
12             Himachal Pradesh                    40
7                  Chhattisgarh                    37
4                         Assam                    36
10                      Gujarat                  3548
5                         Bihar                   345
1   Andaman and Nicobar Islands                    33
25                       Punjab                   313
8                         Delhi                  3108
11                      Haryana                   296
26                    Rajasthan                  2262
18               Madhya Pradesh                  2168
17                       Ladakh                    20
20                      Manipur                     2
29                      Tripura                     2
31                Uttar Pradesh                  1955
```

I don't know why it shows like this it should be 
(1.Maharashtra, 2.Gujarat, 3.Delhi, etc)

complete script [Here](https://github.com/meezanmalek/coronavirus_data/blob/sampe/corona_virus.py)

Comment: Are you sure the datatype of `Total Confirmed cases` is numeric?

Answer (score 0):

simple by converting that column into integer 
`df['Total_Confirmed_cases'] = df['Total_Confirmed_cases'].astype(int)`